# XKB Shift + KP_Subtract: How to map these multiple keys?

Tags: xkb

I've succesfully mapped the `KP_Subtract` to `Home` (in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`):

```
key <KPSU> { [ Home ] };
```

It works fine, BUT, when I also click the `Shift` key (to include the previous text) it becomes `KP_Subtract` again.

Usin `xev`, I see the difference:

`KP_Subtract`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1b5, subw 0x0, time 194171524, (127,582), root:(1726,611),
    state 0x10, keycode 82 (keysym 0xff50, Home), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`Shift_L` + `KP_Subtract`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1b5, subw 0x0, time 194252966, (112,591), root:(1711,620),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x1b5, subw 0x0, time 194253126, (112,591), root:(1711,620),
    state 0x11, keycode 82 (keysym 0xffad, KP_Subtract), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2d) "-"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2d) "-"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I noticed the `state` parameter is different in each run. Also `keysym`.

I realize I need to tell XKB that when both keys are clicked, map it into `Home`. Didn't find it on the docs, nor on G.

How can I fix this? What should I write in which file?

Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Also, it's a simple QWERTY keyboard. I'm looking for a quick solution, rather than defining a keyboard layout.

Comment: setxkbmap -layout us,il